# Post-increment on both sides of assignment, character pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Consider:

```
char *s, *t;
char c;
```

What happens with this assignment?

```
*t++ = *s++;
```

Is this functionally equivalent to (option 1):

```
c = *t;
t++;
*s = c;
s++;
```

Or is it equivalent to this (option 2):

```
c = *s;
s++;
*t = c;
t++;
```

Comment: It's the other way round – the data is first read from `*s` and then written to `*t`;

Comment: To me it makes more sense to look at it like `*t = *s; ++t; ++s;`

Comment: In my distant memory, `while (*t++ = *s++);` was the way to demonstrate you did grok C.

Comment: option 2 is correct. I'm not sure why you would think option 1 could be correct, since the assignment is backwards.

Comment: As to why: Trying to understand effect of post-increment operator on left-hand side of assignment operator.

Comment: @RuudHelderman the classic implementation of `strcpy()`.

Comment: @RuudHelderman `(*t++ = *s++` is _strange_. Grok sounds  _alien_ to me.  In what _land_ might one use that?   [Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok)?  

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Whoa, are you suggesting early PDP-11 and VAX assembly coders came from Mars? Because I'm sure stuff like `MOV (R0)+,(R1)+` inspired Ritchie when designing C, instantly causing `*ptr++` to become idiomatic, both as lvalue and rvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*ptr` and `*ptr++` are idiomatic in C,
but to make it perfectly clear that `*` is a unary operator with a single operand,
I will continue by writing that operand in parentheses.
So let's consider `*(ptr)` and `*(ptr++)`.

For operator `*`, it does not matter what expression we give it.
It is the *return value* of its operand that matters,
as that is the address where data is being read (right operand of assignment) or written (left operand of assignment).

`ptr++` and `ptr` have *the same* return value (given the same state of memory prior to evaluation).
Consequently, the behavior of `*(ptr++)` is identical to that of `*(ptr)`.
The only difference being the *side effect* of `ptr++`: the pointer value is incremented.

But that side effect affects neither the return value of `ptr++` nor the operation of `*`.
I always imagine the post-increment to take place at the end of the statement, but that is just my mental model.
A compiler *may* decide to increment `ptr` earlier, for whatever reason (typically performance gain);
as long as the net effect is the same.

So any C statement containing `*(ptr++)` is basically equivalent to the same statement with `*(ptr)`,
followed by an additional statement `ptr++;`.
This even works when multiple variables are post-incremented, as in your example:

```
*t++ = *s++;
```

is equivalent with:

```
*t = *s;
t++;
s++;
```

Things become tricky when the same pointer variable appears twice in the statement.
That is often undefined behavior (UB),
as the evaluation order of (sub)expressions in the same statement is mostly undefined in C (except for a handful of operators).

```
*s++ = *s++;
```

is **not** (guaranteed to be) equivalent with:

```
*s = *s;
s++;
s++;
```